# Changing Display on HID PivClass

Tags: python, security

I was wondering if it is possible to change the display screen on a HID pivClass.[image]

As you can see here in this image, the display shows "HID Global, PivClass" when there is not an event going on. I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to manipulate this.

Thank you

https://www.hidglobal.com/products/pivclass-rkcl40

here is the link to the product